# SQL запросы

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Доброе время суток уважаемые люди!

В общем в скорем времени мне прийдётся очень плотно изучить SQL запросы, посоветуйте пожалуйста книги/мануалы, с чего вообще начать это дело?

Я в этой сфере не давно, мне нужна некая IDE что бы я писал запрос и она графично показывала что я там накалякал (таблицы, связи, представления и т.д) - есть вообще такая? Если да, то какая лучше? (платная/бесплатная - не имеет разницы)

За ранее спасибо за советы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не много не понял что именно вам нужно, покажу на примере MySQL.

1. Загружаете [Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/);
2. Загружаете [XAMPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/) [либо что-то другое];
3. Устанавливаете Workbench и XAMPP;
4. Заходите в XAMPP включаете MySQL [Рисунок 1];
   [image]
5. Заходите в Workbench, создаёте новое подключение [Рисунок 2];
   [image]
6. Создаёте запросы [Рисунок 3].
   [image]

Comment: Без XAMPP-а, кончено, мускуль с воркбенчем никак не поставить... )

Comment: @Nofate, Я лишь написал то, что использую сам, ибо мне так удобнее. Расписать все возможные варианты можно, но мне кажется это не в этом вопросе, тут идёт речь о том, как что-либо поставить, и начать писать запросы. Ибо я не понял вопроса.

Comment: @Ковальский, спасибо большое, всё нормально заработало, уже начинаю "кодить", вообще то, что нужно, порадовало что ещё и Apache можно оживить с одной программы, вообще крутяк :)

Answer (score 0):

Начать стоит с реляционной алгебры и прочих фундаментальных основ. Тогда будет понимание происходящего и визуализация не потребуется.

Из литературы могу порекомендовать [Системы баз данных. Полный курс](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1351096/). Вроде бы есть даже [посвежее издание](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5640264/).

Comment: Я какую модно ИДЕ, что бы написал там "создать таблицу" с такими то полями и т.д и что бы она отобразилась графично?

Comment: Запросы? Microsoft Access.

Comment: Под разные СУБД разные IDE.

Например:

- Под MS SQL Server - MS SQL Server Management Studio.

- Под MySQL - MySQL Workbench вроде бы был.

Comment: если IDE, to http://hashcode.ru/questions/226645/mysql-ide-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-sql-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86

Answer (score 0):

Ресурсы онлайн:

[Интерактивный учебник по SQL](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/content.html)

[Упражнения по SQL](http://sql-ex.ru/)